# Selectable text not working when using inside FlatList react native

Tags: react-native

When I set `selectable` to Text component inside FlatList, it does not work. It works only without FlatList.

```js
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{
    paddingBottom: groupList.length !== 0 ? 130 : 130 + 51,
    flex: groupList.length !== 0 ? undefined : 1,
  }}
  ListHeaderComponent={<Text selectable>'Hello'</Text>}
  ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyList />}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={groupList}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <GroupItem group={item} {...props} />}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `removeClippedSubviews={false}`   in  `FlatList`

Comment: Worked for me, thanks 